# Why does Git show deleted files after switching a branch?

Tags: git, github

I keep seeing deleted files every time I switch branches. I already committed all the changes I had done.

```
git checkout master
D   eqs.jpg
D   old conversion.pdf
D   readme.txt
```

What should I do to avoid it?

Comment: git rm --cached qs.jpg old_conversion.pdf readme.txt

Comment: Can you add output of  command "git status"? (It will help)

Comment: If you are using Git 2.7.0 and sparse checkouts, then this might be a known issue, solved in 2.7.1: *"The ignore mechanism saw a few regressions around untracked file listing and sparse checkout selection areas in 2.7.0; the change that is responsible for the regression has been reverted."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that you have deleted the three files locally, but have not committed that deletion. If you want the files deleted from the repository as well, you need to `git add --all` and `git commit`. If you do not want them deleted, do a `git checkout .` to restore them locally.

Answer (score -2):

You have to clean your working folder or to commit the changes.

#### How to clean the working dir?

```
# (x/X) are different case
git clean -Xfd
git clean -xfd
```

> #### -x
>
> Don’t use the standard ignore rules read from .gitignore (per directory) and $GIT_DIR/info/exclude, but do still use the ignore rules given with `-e` options.
>
> This allows removing all untracked files, including build products.
>   This can be used (possibly in conjunction with `git reset`) to create a pristine working directory to test a clean build.
>
> #### -X
>
> Remove only files ignored by Git.
>   This may be useful to rebuild everything from scratch, but keep manually created files.

---

#### How to clean cache?

# remove the file from cache
   git clean --cached

---

#### How to commit a removed file?

```
git add -A
# or:
git rm --cached <file>
```